# How to scroll the scrollview as per text Content Size in ios

Tags: ios, swift

In my project, I am adding a UIScrollview on view controller programmatically and also the content view on this scrollview.

Then I have added two textviews on content-view and here my problem: I want the embedded text views to expand or shrink according to the text size they hold.

I seem to get the first text view expanded properly, but the second one does not seem to expand properly and instead some text is cropped in it. I want it working universally in all devices.

I have searched a lot but I did not get solution. My code is below, please help me.

### my code:-

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    {
        UITextView * TextView;
        UITextView * TextView1;

        UIScrollView * scrollView;
        UIView * containerView;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];

        containerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        [scrollView addSubview:containerView];

        NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(scrollView,containerView);

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView(600)]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

        TextView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
        TextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        TextView.text = @"De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.De Villiers currently holds the record for the fastest 50, fastest 100 and fastest 150 in ODIs. The team that has suffered the most at the hands of this right-handed genius has been the West Indies.";
        TextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [containerView addSubview:TextView];

        TextView1 = [UITextView new];
        TextView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        TextView1.text = @"He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.He smashed the fastest ODI off just 16 balls during the second ODI against West Indies in Johannesburg in January 2015. He had broken the 19-year mark off 17 balls set by Sanath Jayasuriya against Pakistan in Singapore in 1996.";
        TextView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [containerView addSubview:TextView1];

        //Applying autolayouts for textview1
        NSLayoutConstraint * constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:200.0f];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];


        //Applying autolayouts for textview2
        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: TextView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:20.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

        constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:containerView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0f constant:-5.0f];
        [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];

constraint2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:TextView1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:200.0f];
    [containerView addConstraint:constraint2];


        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];

        [scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[containerView(==scrollView)]|"
                                                                           options:0
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:views]];
    }

    @end
```

[image]

Comment: So do you say your first text view is doing the right thing? It is expanding properly?

Comment: Also have you taken a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: i mean second textview data is not visible to user that means i want scroll the content view for showing that second textview

Comment: what is that documant that's not solution to my question

Comment: That is not the solution, a document that has some pointers on using auto layout with scroll view, just a hint.

Comment: i mean dynamically i want to change scrollview content size in i phone inches

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88797/discussion-between-ramakrishna-and-shripada).